# Como mostrar erro retornado do backend em nodejs no react

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, http-status

To com um problema em mostrar a mensagem de erro que veio do backend. Eu retorno no backend:

> res.status(400).send({error: "Usuario já existe"});

já no front eu gostaria de exibir essa mensagem, ao invés da mensagem padrão que é mostrada:

> Request failed with status code 400

como eu posso receber e mostrar essa mensagem vinda do backend?

codigo front-end:

```
try{
    //sucess
}catch(error){
    console.log(`$error`);
}
```

Comment: coloque na pergunta o código javascript onde trata o retorno do backend

Comment: se possível, mande o retorno da sua response -> console.log(response)

Comment: Acredito que você esteja usando o axios para fazer a requisição, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
  // Faça aqui sua requisição
  const response = await http.get("http://exemplo")
} catch (error) {
  // Caso a requisição dentro do try falhe
  // este bloco captará o erro
  const mensagem = error.response.error 
  // Aqui você acessa o objeto que retornou do backend
  // Faça o que quiser com ele
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So precisa ler a propriedade status da sua response quando trata a receção da mesma no front-end

Dependendo de como estas a enviar a informação esta aqui um exemplo de como podes fazer isso.

```
  function(res){
      if(res.status > 302){
        console.log(res);
      }
  }
```

para fazer dentro de um `try catch` necessitas usar o `throw`

Answer (score -2):

Sé pegar o error.response

```
} catch(error) {
    setAuthenticated(false);
    const { data } = error.response;
    alert(data.message);
}
```